# iOS touches get stuck when multiple touches are too close together?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ipad, touch

My problem relates to this page:
http://bokehcreative.co.uk/projects/touch.html

It is a simple touch tracker and counter but when two touches get too close it SOMETIMES seems to register .touchend on only one of them. I can understand why this would happen but am not sure what to do to prevent it.

Any help is appreciated and more details can be posted if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

iOS is doing it's best to interpret the user interaction and you can't change the number of touches that iOS 'thinks' it sees.  However, within your code based on what you 'think' the user is trying to do, you can make adjustments: ignore a touch end when you still have active touches (you could even move the spot that the touch ended by assuming it moves with the others - if it was doing so initially), warn that the touches are too close, continue to mark the spot with the circle until the touch returns.

If you need more help, add more detail on what you are trying to accomplish.